# Mocking DbSet.AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, moq

I am following the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) to try to mock my `DbSet` and `DbContext` for unit testing using Moq.

The service that I'm testing looks like this

```
public class MyItemService
{
   private MyContext context;

   public void AddItem(MyItem item)
   {
      this.context.MyItems.AddOrUpdate(item);
      this.context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

My unit test looks like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddItem_ShouldSucceed()
{
    var myItems = new Mock<DbSet<MyItem>>();

    var context = new Mock<MyContext>();
    context.Setup(e => e.MyItems).Returns(myItems.Object);          

    MyItemService service = new MyItemService(context.Object);

    service.AddItem(new MyItem
    {
        Id = "1234"
    });
}
```

When I run the test, I am getting the exception

``` System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to call public, instance method AddOrUpdate on derived IDbSet<T> type 'Castle.Proxies.DbSet``1Proxy'. Method not found. ```

I assume the problem is because `AddOrUpdate` is an extension method on `DbSet`.  I **do** have `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` included in my test .cs file.

I tried adding the line

```
myItems.Setup(e => e.AddOrUpdate(It.IsAny<MyItem>()));
```

to my unit test, but then I get the exception

System.NotSupportedException: Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: e => e.AddOrUpdate(new[] { It.IsAny() })

Is there any way that I can have my unit test work when my method being tested is using `AddOrUpdate`?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/35203698/920557

Comment: Moq cannot mock extension methods. Suggestion, abstract the DbContext behind an interface and have in instance `AddOrUpdate` method that can be mocked. Have your context implement the interface while internally calling the extension method

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko I use new `DbContext`s inside of each my "get", "add", and "update" service method, so unfortunately simply calling `SaveChanges` won't work for me.

Comment: @Nkosi That's an good idea.  I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: @BenRubin I am trying to understand if the `AddOrUpdate` in the `MyItemService.AddItem` example was meant for the context or the dbset?

Comment: @Nkosi Good catch!  I had an error in the example.  I corrected it so that I call `AddOrUpdate` on the `DbSet`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across this old question after searching for similar issue.

All we need to do is to create **MockableDbSetWithExtensions** abstract class, and use it instead of ***DbSet***, whenever you want to test a method which calls ***AddOrUpdate***.

[It is how Entity Framework team tests their code too.](https://github.com/Icehunter/entityframework/blob/master/test/EntityFramework/FunctionalTests/TestDoubles/MockableDbSetTests.cs#L84)

```
public abstract class MockableDbSetWithExtensions<T> : DbSet<T>
    where T : class
{
    public abstract void AddOrUpdate(params T[] entities);
    public abstract void AddOrUpdate(Expression<Func<T, object>> 
         identifierExpression, params T[] entities);
}
```

### Usage

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddItem_ShouldSucceed()
{
    var myItems = new Mock<MockableDbSetWithExtensions<MyItem>>();

    var context = new Mock<MyContext>();
    context.Setup(e => e.MyItems).Returns(myItems.Object);

    MyItemService service = new MyItemService(context.Object);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Nkosi said in the comments you add wrapper around the AddOrUpdate. 
You can implement the wrapper like this:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext 
{
    public virtual DbSet<MyItem> Items {get; set;}

    public virtual AddOrUpdate<T>(T item)
    {
         if(typeof(T) == typeof(MyItem))
         {
             Items.AddOrUpdate(item as MyItem)
         }
    }
}
```

And then call it from your class like:

```
public class MyItemService
{
   private MyContext context;

   public void AddItem(MyItem item)
   {
      this.context.AddOrUpdate(item);
      this.context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```